# Ruby on Rails to create and access MySQL variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How to use Ruby on Rails to do this?

```
mysql> SET @t1=1, @t2=2, @t3:=4;
mysql> SELECT @t1, @t2, @t3, @t4 := @t1+@t2+@t3;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `ActiveRecord::Base.connection`:

```
>> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SET @t1=1, @t2=2, @t3:=4;")
 => nil 
>> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_one(
    "SELECT @t1, @t2, @t3, @t4 := @t1+@t2+@t3;")
 => {"@t1"=>"1", "@t2"=>"2", "@t4 := @t1+@t2+@t3"=>"7", "@t3"=>"4"}
```

For more methods you can use on this class, see [the documentation here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html).

You can also call the `connection` method on any ActiveRecord class you have defined. For instance, if you have a model called `Post`, you can use `Post.connection.execute("sql")`.